# What software should I use for creating sound files for game development?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound-editor

I am developing games on python, I need some easy to use software that can create sound files. Format can be anything .midi, .mid, .wav, .mp3 it doesn't matter. I can also download games sound from Internet, but I want to make my own sound for the games. The software must be easy to use, and if that software is lightweight that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both the [**Linux MultiMedia Studio**](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) (lmss) at  which seems to be an alternative or similar software to Fruity Loops, Sony Acid, etc. It allows you to sample audio files, insert percussions, read/write midi's, etc.

If you are familiar to Fruity Loops,Sony Acid and these style of software you will feel comfortable with LMMS.

Screenshot provided right here for your convenience:

[image]

Another great sound work station is the [**Energy XT**](http://www.energy-xt.com/), which is indeed proprietary (closed source), running natively on linux and these days they have a "free" version which allows you to do some limited things like saving but including only 1 synth, 3 percussions and these things. The fancy of this is that it is really easy to use and it runs natively on linux.

Videos can be reached right here: http://www.energy-xt.com/index.php?id=0101

And a screenshot from my desktop for you to see the full version of energyXT at work is also here:

[image]

Both these are ready to run, but if you wish try finding alternatives to these applications, I suggest you this site: http://alternativeto.net/ on which you can perform searching for almost any known application.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks! i hope lmms will be easy to use. i am not going for energyXT since its not open source and gives limited features

Comment: http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/0.4:Manual and this is the documentation for lmms and its great

Comment: energyXT provides full features after purchasing. Which is indeed one of the useful tools that I am using for making sound and music. Anyway, it's nice to know that you will give lmms a try and I am sure that you will be pleased with the performance. Several tools can be added to lmms such as oscilators, vst's, etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake<sup>+</sup> you can use software created for making *sound effects for games*.

There is **[Bfxr](http://www.bfxr.net/)**, which is a browser tool (flash), but there is an Air version.

[image: Bfxr]

You can use the option to save the created effect as a wav file.

Bfxr's nephew is **[sfxr](http://www.drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html)**. Originally Bfxr was based upon sfxr.

[image: Sfxr]

Sfxr was ported to Linux and [known](http://n3wt0n.com/blog/drpetters-sfxr-with-ubuntu-810/) to compile under Ubuntu 8.10, although I'm not sure if it is possible to compile under 11.10.

Both software has a steep learning curve: just start tweaking the sliders, press the buttons and I bet you'll smile.

*<sup>+</sup> Note: Since these are not Linux software (except for the second, but I cannot check) I include them after an accepted answer.*

Comment: [SFXR](http://drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html) now has a deb.

Answer (score 0):

**[Audacity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/)** is a featured sound editor available right in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: the features of audacity says that you can modify sound tracks and didn't said anything about creating my own sound files(as per Ubuntu Software Center)

Comment: @subhojit777 You can create sound files using Audacity as well, not just edit. In fact, I've created sound effects for my own personal game project this way. Audacity provides plenty of tools for generating different kinds of sounds to start with, and from there you can edit them in any way you want.